# Sending multiple checkbox values to NancyFX when the form encoding is multipart/form-data

Tags: multipartform-data, nancy

I have a `<form>` tag that contains a checkbox list. When the form enctype = `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` the multiple selected checkbox values are presented to me as a comma delimited string via the `Request.Form` as expected.

If I change the enctype to `multipart/form-data` (because I want to include a profile image in the submission) then only the last selected checkbox value is presented via `Request.Form` despite all the selected checkbox values (with the same name) being present in the request payload.

**Example Payload**

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryS2gp8PRUhbFngzPE
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="expertise-areas"

Academic career path
------WebKitFormBoundaryS2gp8PRUhbFngzPE
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="expertise-areas"

Promotion
```

**Route Code**

```
var expertise = Request.Form.expertiseareas;
```

**Results**

```
Expected : "Academic career path,Promotion"
Actual   : "Promotion"
```

Is this by design? If so, what is the best way to send a list of checkbox values with a small image? Do I need to break this apart into two forms?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting an array in the name attribute of your html input tag, i.e. `name="expertise-areas[]"`? At least this is how it works in PHP: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it out but unfortunately it did not work. Interestingly, Nancy did treat the '[]' named value as an array, when binding to a strongly typed class at least, but it still only plucked the final value from the payload to populate the array. I will keep researching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I got it working:

1. Prevent the checkboxes from being posted with the form by removing
   the name attribute
2. Add a hidden input to hold the selected values as a comma-delimited list
3. Use javascript to join the the selected checkbox values into a
   comma-delimited list
4. Set the hidden input value to the comma-delimited list

I just yanked this code from my project but you get the idea.

**HTML (razor)**

```
<form id="form-profile-edit" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="/user/profile/edit">
... more stuff
    <input id="organisational-hidden" name="organisationalareas" type="hidden"/>
    @foreach (string area in Model.OrganisationalAreas)
    {
        @Html.GetAreaCheckbox(area, 
                              user.HasOrgansiationalArea(area), 
                              @class:"organisational")
    }
...more stuff
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#form-profile-edit').ajaxForm({
    beforeSerialize: function() {
        var organisational = toCommaDelimited($('.organisational:checked'));
        $('#organisational-hidden').val(organisational);
    }
});
function toCommaDelimited(checkboxes) {
    return $.map(checkboxes, function (checkbox) { return checkbox.value; }).join(',');
}
```